# Selectively show and hide code within Python notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I remember seeing someone creating a Python notebook in which you could only see some texts and plots, but there was a button for showing the code that generated the plots. Does anyone know how to do that?

I have seen some people using Javascript to do that but couldn't find anything clearly explaining the steps.

Comment: are you just asking how to use the editor ?

Comment: notebook has menu `View` with `Collapse Selected Code` and `Expand Selected Code`

Comment: No, I mean in the rendered html file of a notebook.